# Multiple imports with vue

Tags: vue.js, import, module, components

I have about 20 forms which get switched using a dynamic component

```
 <component v-bind:is="activeForm"></component
```

Rather than have about 20 of these

```
 import Concentform from '../forms/concentForm'
```

and 20 declarations

```js
export default {
  components: {
     Concentform,
     anotherForm,
     moreForms,
 }
}
```

Can I do a mass import?

Comment: For importing named modules, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34573779/4636715

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add `index.js` under `../forms` with

   ```
   import Concentform from './concentForm'
   export default {
       Concentform
   }
   ```
2. Import all in once (default) `import forms from '../forms/'`
3. Set components

```
export default {
  components: {
     ...forms,
     otherComponent
  }
}
```

Comment: I have seen lots of ways using regex and all kinds of crazy stuff but that seems the cleanest.